# Generating .java from onvif .wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, onvif

I write a Java app which work with camera. I get files from onvif site [devicemgmt.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl) and generate .java files using wsimport.exe. It works well but it has not enough methods for me. I need to receive events from the camera like motion detection or closing contacts of button. I tried to use [deviceIOPort](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/deviceio.wsdl) as .wsdl file.
One note: I added to my .wsdl file this *service*:

```
   <wsdl:service name="DeviceService">
         <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">
           <soap:address location="http://ip/onvif/device_service"/>
         </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

It works fine for devicemgmt.wsdl, but when I use this for deviceIOPort it works, but no new methods are added.

To generate java files, I use the command :

```
wsimport -d where_to_place_generated_files ..\deviceIOBinding.wsdl -keep -Xnocompile -verbose > ..\log.txt
```

How can I use `deviceIOPort` and add custom methods at the same time.

P.S. if you find mistakes send it to me, i am still learning english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i added to the file *deviceIOPort.wsdl* after `<wsdl:binding>` this:

```
   <wsdl:service name="DeviceService">
         <wsdl:port name="DeviceIOPort" binding="tmd:DeviceIOBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://ip/onvif/device_service"/>
         </wsdl:port>
         <wsdl:port name="MediaPort" binding="trt:MediaBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://ip/onvif/device_service"/>
         </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://ip/onvif/device_service"/>
         </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

new methods were added and worked well for me. 
And one note: i just download from [www.onvif.org](http://www.onvif.org/) by [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) all onvif files specifications and use it. If you want to download files separately and then use it you have to change in `<import>` `location` attribute.